# Libgdx blast from a gun

Tags: java, algorithm, animation, libgdx

in my game there is a tank. I got a Barrel class that extends `Sprite` this class is taking care of the the barrel related stuff, One of those things is the blast animation when shooting. This is how I tried to do it:

```
batch.draw(currShotAnimation,
            b2body.getPosition().x - currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth() / 2,
            b2body.getPosition().y + 10,
            0,
            0,
            currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth(),
            currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight(),
            1,
            1,
            getRotation());
```

when the tank looks forward it's working: 
[image: top down tank game]
but when he looks to different places it's looks weird:
[image: tank looking right]

[image: tank looking down]
how can I fix it so it will work to all directions?

EDIT: 
after trying what `Abhishek Aryan` suggested (my pixels to meter is one):

```
        batch.draw(currShotAnimation,
            b2body.getPosition().x + offset * MathUtils.cosDeg(getRotation()),
            b2body.getPosition().y + offset * MathUtils.sinDeg(getRotation()),
            currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth()/2f,
            currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight()/2f,
            currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth(),
            currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight(),
            1,
            1,
            getRotation());
```

it looks like this: 
[image: tank problem1]
[image: tank problem2]

Comment: is this solved? It look likes your problem is how your computing your angle

Comment: @lan yes, jest added one more photo so it will be clrearer

Comment: @Roni Could you maybe take out the code for the rotation and just let it at  0. Then it is easier to see if maybe the positioning already works, or if it's the rotating that's messing up.

Comment: @Leon currently not at my house. Will do it when I get back home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `b2body` is your box2d body ? If yes then convert meter into pixel for drawing on screen.

```
private float offset=10;
private float METER_PIXEL=32;

batch.draw(textureRegion,b2body.getPosition().x*METER_PIXEL+ offset *MathUtils.cosDeg(getRotation()),b2body.getPosition().y*METER_PIXEL+ offset*MathUtils.sinDeg(getRotation()),currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth()/2f,currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight()/2f,currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth(),currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight(),1,1,getRotation());
```

Here you're using sprite Rotation for rotation of your flame animation. So you need to rotate your Sprite according to b2dbody rotation so that you can use here otherwise here you need to get b2body rotation in radian and convert into degree and use here.

Here I tested offset for a TextureRegion

```
 public class TestGame extends Game implements InputProcessor{

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private TextureRegion textureRegion;
    private float offset = 20;
    private firstTex,secondTex; 

    @Override
    public void create() {

        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();

        textureRegion=new TextureRegion(firstTex=new Texture("im.png"));
        sprite=new Sprite(secondTex=new Texture("xyz.png"));
        sprite.setPosition(100,100);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion,sprite.getX()+ offset *MathUtils.cosDeg(sprite.getRotation()),sprite.getY()+(offset)*MathUtils.sinDeg(sprite.getRotation()),sprite.getWidth()/2f,sprite.getHeight()/2f,sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),1,1,sprite.getRotation());
        spriteBatch.end();

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            float rotation=sprite.getRotation();
            rotation++;
            sprite.setRotation(rotation);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        float rotation=sprite.getRotation();
        rotation++;
        sprite.setRotation(rotation);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
       firstTex.dispose();
       secondTex.dispose();
       spriteBatch.dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still got some problems, jest edited my post

Comment: Is b2body is your box2d body ?

Comment: then need to convert box2d position into pixel by this b2body.getPosition().x*METER_PIXEL for drawing, same for y direction also

Comment: my METER_PIXEL is one so its not the problem.btw I shered my code with your github if you want to take a look

Comment: please provide me your project link

Comment: Im working on it with bitbucket so I shard it with you. Did you got it?  If not provied me with your mail and i'll send you

Comment: Is you're repo is private on bitbucket, if not you can send me your repo link.

Comment: got it. let me check.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that the `draw` method draws the object at its lower left corner and also rotates around this. If you want to see what I mean raplace the position with this:

```
b2body.getPosition().x,
b2body.getPosition().y,
```

Now your blast should be always rotating and be postioned at its lower left corner. Now, try to set your originx and originy, which are  both currently `0` to

```
currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth() / 2,
0,
```

This way your sprite will *rotate* around its bottom center, which should make things easier. However it will still be *positioned* at its lower left corner. You can't however just add some values, which is what you are doing above. If your barrel is pointing downwards you dont want to add 10 to the y value, which will push the sprite upwards, since it should be pushed downwards a bit, so it is below your tank. You will need to use some trigonometry to position you sprite accoring to its rotation. Look [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/libgdx-move-sprite-in-the-direction-of-other-sprite) for a very similar problem. I hope you understand your problem now.

Comment: I tried this as well with the trigonometry of `Abhishek Aryan` but still it's not working

Answer (score 2):

The second and third parameter in your `batch.draw()` is your problem. If you want to centre it you should divide it with your `currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth()` by half. So it should be like this:

```
batch.draw(currShotAnimation,
        b2body.getPosition().x + offset * MathUtils.cosDeg(getRotation()) - currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth() / 2,
        b2body.getPosition().y + offset * MathUtils.sinDeg(getRotation()) - currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight() / 2,
        currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth()/2f,
        currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight()/2f,
        currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth(),
        currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight(),
        1,
        1,
        getRotation());
```

This will centre the point origin in your image while rotating.

UPDATE: I think the way you're computing your angle is wrong.it should be like this

```
   b2body.getPosition().y +=  (Math.sin(rotation) * speed);
   b2body.getPosition().x +=  (Math.cos(rotation) * speed);
```

And in your `batch.draw(); x and y parameter change it to:

```
 b2body.getPosition().x -  currShotAnimation.getRegionWidth() / 2
 b2body.getPosition().y -  currShotAnimation.getRegionHeight() / 2
```

this should center the origin point.

Comment: @lan I will test it when I get home